# how to improve my validation accuracy in transfer learning Resnet50?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I am training a model, and using Resnet50 weights, my train accuracy improves during more epochs but validation accuracy is lower than train accuracy and did not improve.
what is the reason?
bellow is my code for transfer learning

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
import cv2
import os
print(os.listdir("/kaggle/input/contaguis-skin-diease-dataset/Contaguis_Skin_Diease_dataset/Train"))

NUM_CLASSES = 5

CHANNELS = 3

IMAGE_RESIZE = 224
RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE = 'avg'
DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION = 'softmax'
OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION = 'categorical_crossentropy'

LOSS_METRICS = ['accuracy']

NUM_EPOCHS = 20
EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE = 3

STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING = 10
STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION = 10

BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING = 100
BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION = 100
BATCH_SIZE_TESTING = 1
```

## using tensorflow.keras

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

## resNet 50

```
resnet_weights_path = '/kaggle/input/resnet50/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'

model = Sequential()

model.add(ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = RESNET50_POOLING_AVERAGE, weights = resnet_weights_path))
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu')) #
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation = DENSE_LAYER_ACTIVATION))

model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

## optimizers

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01, decay = 1e-6, momentum = 0.9, nesterov = True)
model.compile(optimizer = sgd, loss = OBJECTIVE_FUNCTION, metrics = LOSS_METRICS)

from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_size = IMAGE_RESIZE

# preprocessing_function is applied on each image but only after re-sizing & augmentation (resize => augment => pre-process)
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

# flow_From_directory generates batches of augmented data (where augmentation can be color conversion, etc)
train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/kaggle/input/contaguis-skin-diease-dataset/Contaguis_Skin_Diease_dataset/Train',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_TRAINING,
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        '/kaggle/input/contaguis-skin-diease-dataset/Contaguis_Skin_Diease_dataset/Valid',
        target_size=(image_size, image_size),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VALIDATION,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

## using callbacks to prevent model overfitting

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

cb_early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', patience = EARLY_STOP_PATIENCE)
cb_checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath = '../working/best.hdf5', monitor = 'val_loss', save_best_only = True, mode = 'auto')
```

## Training my Model with 20 epochs

```
fit_history = model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_TRAINING,
        epochs = NUM_EPOCHS,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH_VALIDATION,
        callbacks=[cb_checkpointer, cb_early_stopper]
)
model.load_weights("../working/best.hdf5")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BozX6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw3jZ.png)

Comment: This indicates overfitting. An extreme example: if you train a classifier many epochs on a single data point, the training accuracy gets close to one, however, that does not generalise enough to predict unseen labels correctly. This can be mostly due to not having enough number of training examples.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: I would add more training examples. How large is your dataset?

Comment: I have 300 per class for training purpose

Comment: That doesn't indicate anything. The number of images required for a good model heavily depends on the similarity of the pre-trained model to the in-hand task and also the "natural" difficulty of the task. For example, good face detection models are trained on datasets of millions of examples. If you are not satisfied with the results, changing the model to something else (senet, xception, ...) might help as well.

Comment: my training data is not similar to pre-trained model, my dataset is skin disease dataset

Comment: Can I ask, is it necessary/does it matter whether preprocess_input is before or after data augmentation? I am new to transfer learning.